# why do I get 'inject' undefined error when using Jasmine with Angular?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am Jasmine/AngularJS unit testing newbie. I created a simple angular app to add two numbers so that I can learn how to write unit tests for Angular App. The [Angular Doc on unit test is incomplete](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.unit-testing#!).Based on the blogs and stack overflow answers, I build my first test and I am running into 'injector' undefined error. I am using Jasmine framework for the unit testing. 
**HTML**

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="additionCtrl">
    First Number: <input ng-model="NumberOne"/><br/>
    Second Number: <input ng-model="NumberTwo"/>
    <button ng-click="add(NumberOne, NumberTwo)">Add</button><br/>
    Result: {{Result}}
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/additionCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
function additionCtrl($scope) {
$scope.NumberOne = 0;
$scope.NumberTwo = 0;
$scope.Result = 0;
$scope.add = function (a, b) {
};
}
```

Jasmine spec file.

```
describe("Addition", function () {
var $scope, ctrl;

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    this.scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('additionCtrl', {
       $scope: this.scope 
    });
}));

it("should add two integer numbers.", inject(function ($controller) {        
    expect(ctrl.add(2, 3)).toEqual(5);
}));
});
```

Specrunner.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-mocks.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../App/Scripts/additionCtrl.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/addition.spec.js"></script>
```

This is a failing test and once the test fails with the expected result then I can modify the code to make it pass, but I am facing the problem with somehow angular mock is not getting injector. 
I saw an example where I can newup a controller instead of using injector, but I would like to try to learn on using injector so that I am set up more complex tests.
 I might be missing something simple here. Please direct me to any write up I might have missed.
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For future reference here's a Plunker with a full unit test setup (for the answer to your question I was about to post)

http://plnkr.co/edit/KZGKM6

Useful to have this setup available for sharing test scenarios.

Comment: This is what I have been looking for some time :)

Answer (score 11):

Found the problem, the url I was using to access angular-mock was wrong. I changed it to "http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular-mocks.js" and also changed the order of the script tags to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

now it is failing on the method as it is supposed to be.

Comment: For AngularJS 1.2.5, angular-mocks.js is available as hosted library here https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-mocks.js, so, no need to use the code.angularjs.org website.